# Branch based deployment in Microsoft Appcenter

Tags: android, ios, react-native, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I need to deploy apps to app store for each branch. I have DEV, PROD, Staging and UAT environments. Each has a separate branch. What i need to build and deploy each branch to separate app in app store.

The problem is I can only add a single app in app store connect. If i try to add again, it says **'already connected'**.

Anyone knows any solution for branch based deployment to store??
I couldn't find any articles mentioning these kind of scenarios.

***Scenario***

Single Repo

Dev Branch      ---> Dev_App

Staging branch  ---> Staging_App

I have separate apps in app store for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it is normally discouraged to have multiple versions on the AppStore. I would think you would run `DEV` locally, `STAGING` on devices that download a release build from AppCenter, and `PROD` on the AppStore.

If you really wanted different versions on the AppStore, you would probably need to change the BundleIdentifier per release. You can find this in the `Info.plist` file.